# Why does `docker images` also show the base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a **very** simple dockerfile

```
FROM makuk66/docker-solr
MAINTAINER test
```

Which I then build using

```
docker build -t myimage/test .
```

From what I know about Docker when I type `docker images` it should only show `myimage/test` under `REPOSITORY`; however this is not what happens. Instead, I see:

```
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
myimage/test          latest              566ef17fc0bc        15 hours ago        1.034 GB
makuk66/docker-solr   latest              bdd8b134dd2d        6 days ago          1.034 GB
```

Why is the base image appearing? [The repository that I am pulling from](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr/blob/master/5.1/Dockerfile) for example has

```
FROM java:8
```

But this doesn't appear. So in this case why is the base image there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your docker build command will do this:

- Search "makuk66/docket-solr" in local, if it cannot find it, then it will try to download it from docker-hub
- Build a layer on top of it with MAINTAINER info and if successful, this will commit it with the image name "myimage/test"

So you are supposed to see both the images.

Comment: Ok so my concern is that both images is that both images are taking up 1.034 GB. Is this actually the case? And if it is, is there a better way for me to build my own docker based from that image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large - might help