# DockerFile one-line vs multi-line instruction

Tags: docker, dockerfile

To my knowledge of the way docker build works is that for each line of instruction, it creates a separate image/layer. However, it is very efficient in managing to reuse the layers or avoid rebuilding those layers if nothing has changed.

So does it matter if I put below instruction either on same line or multi-line? For convenience, I would prefer the single line option unless it is not an efficient option.

**Multi-Line Instruction**

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install ...
```

**Single-Line Instruction**

```
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple RUN vs. single chained RUN in Dockerfile, what is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-what-is-better)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this specific case it is important to put `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` together.  More broadly, fewer layers is considered "better" but it almost never has a perceptible difference.

In practice I tend to group together "related" commands into the same `RUN` command.  If I need to configure and install a package from source, that can get grouped together, and even if I change `make` arguments I don't mind re-running `configure`.  If I need to configure and install three packages, they'd go into separate `RUN` lines.

The important difference in this specific `apt-get` example is around layer caching.  Let's say your Dockerfile has

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install package-a
```

If you run `docker build` a second time, it will decide it's already run all three of these commands and the input hasn't changed, so it will run very quickly and you'll get an identical image out.

Now you come back a day or two later and realize you were missing something, so you change

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install package-a package-b
```

When you run `docker build` again, Docker decides it's already run `apt-get update` and can jump straight to the `apt-get install` line.  In this specific case you'll have trouble: Debian and Ubuntu update their repositories fairly frequently, and when they do the old versions of packages get deleted.  So your `apt-get update` from two days ago points at a package that no longer exists, and your build will fail.

You'll avoid this specific problem by always putting the two `apt-get` commands together in the same `docker run` line

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      package-a \
      package-b
```

Comment: How is putting both apt-get commands into a single RUN command avoids this specific problem? Doesn't Docker decide that it ran the command before, also in this case? What makes it re-run the RUN operation, the apt-get install command?

Comment: If Docker sees the text of a `RUN` line changes, it re-runs the entire line.  If `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` are on separate lines, but the `update` hasn't changed, the `install` will run on an old version of the package index (and possibly fail).  But if they're on the same line, it forces Docker to run `update` and `install` together, and you'll always be using a current version of the package index.

Answer (score 4):

I would use single-line instruction. It's considered to be a [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) for docker. So that you minimize number of layers(`RUN` is one of instructions that create layers).

As of multiple instructions for collecting dependencies, sometimes it's useful during development, if you're frequently changing list of packages(or their versions). But for production image, i would avoid that.