# Dockerfile: using RUN statement with pip install -U pip

Tags: python, docker, pip

[Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) gives the following recommendation for `apt-get update` usage:

> Always combine RUN apt-get update with apt-get install in the same RUN
> statement.

Should I also use the same rule with `pip install -U pip`? E.g. which pratice is preferable inside Dockerfile:

```
# Separate statements
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.46

# Single statement
RUN pip install -U pip && pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.46
```

Comment: You are specifying the version of the package to install so I doubt that it would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The takeaway from the Dockerfile best practices is to **remove caches in the same layer that they are created**. With `pip`, this means using the `--no-cache-dir` option or explicitly removing the cache after installs.

The two code snippets will lead to the same image size in the end. But docker also recommends using fewer layers when possible, so I would prefer the first way (with one `RUN` instruction).

```
RUN pip install -U --no-cache-dir pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python==4.4.0.46
```

```
RUN pip install -U --no-cache-dir pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python==4.4.0.46
```

---

The recommendation about `apt-get update && apt-get install ...` doesn't really apply to `pip`. Apt relies on some files that are downloaded by `apt-get update`, and good practice is to remove these files after any `apt-get install`. This reduces Docker image size. Pip always asks the internet about the available packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61439544/10785101) SO answer. In short, you should always `apt-get update` before you `apt-get install`. Keeping these statements on different lines means that Docker will cache them separately. If you re-run the Docker build, Docker may use the cached `apt-get update` and thus install old packages.

This is not the same with pip - it will always try to install the latest package version available (unless you specified a version explicitly). In the case you have given, you can shorten the statement to `RUN pip install -U pip opencv-python==4.4.0.46`.

As a matter of convenience, you might want to group your installs in different `RUN` statemets, so that the Dockerfile is easier to read, and you don't have to reinstall everything in case you want to add/remove a package. So, for example, if you have `pip` and `opencv` on a single line and you add `pytest` on that same line, when you run `docker build` again, it will install `pip` and `opencv` as well. If, on the other hand, you split the lines like so:

```
RUN pip install -U pip opencv-python
RUN pip install -U pytest
```

and build, Docker will (by default) use the cached installs of `pip` and `opencv` and install only `pytest`. If you have many packages this is a serious time-saver.

The same thing applies to `apt-get`, by the way - the only catch is that, as explained, you would probably want to group `apt-get install` and `apt-get update` on one line for each group of package installs.

In case you don't use caching (i.e. you run something like `docker build . --no-cache`), then it wouldn't matter whether you have everything on one line or on separate lines.