# docker build with Ubuntu 18.04 image hangs after prompting for Country of origin for keyboard

Tags: docker, build, ubuntu-18.04

When I build a Ubuntu 18.04 image with docker it prompts for

> Country of origin for keyboard:

and after I enter a number it hangs. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers 
RUN apt install nvidia-driver-440 -y
```

What do I have to do to build a ubuntu 18.04 image with Docker?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can skip that interactive input if you set this environment variable: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`.

The Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
RUN apt install nvidia-driver-440 -y
```

Comment: The key is that DEBIAN_FRONTEND has to be set in the Dockerfile, not in the host you are building from.

Comment: It's also important for layer-caching purposes to do `apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same `RUN` instruction, and I generally set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` only in that single `RUN` line to avoid it leaking out to the rest of the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze, how do you set it in the same line?

Comment: Simply chain the commands with `&&`, exactly as David suggested in the previous comment. E.g: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install`. This will only add one layer in the UFS instead of two. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-which-is-better) post useful in respect to optimisation of the layers created during a docker build.

Answer (score 4):

- Most issues will be solved by adding `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in your `Dockerfile`.
- Sometimes though, I still get this warning even with this line. This extra line fixes this:

  - `RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections`
  - I took that line from [GitHub issue:
    Error debconf: unable to initialize frontend](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27988#issuecomment-462809153)

---

```bash
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```