# Can I combine COPY directives in Dockerfile to minimize number of image layers?

Tags: docker

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-what-is-better), explaining how it is better to have a combined `RUN` directive instead of multiple `RUN`s, (i.e. `RUN a && b && c` is better than `RUN a; RUN b; RUN c;`).

I want to do the same for the `COPY` directive.

In case of the same dst, I can just do `COPY /src/a/ /src/b/* /src/*/c dst/`. However, when having multiple destinations, I can't do it.

I tried `COPY src/a dst/a && src/b dst/b` but it failed:

`/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder.../&&: no such file or directory`

meaning the `&&` wasn't parsed correctly.

Is there a way to have a concise `COPY` directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have multiple destinations per `COPY` directive. If you want to use just a single `COPY` then, if possible, build your directory structure outside the container so that it matches the expected result inside of the container and just copy the whole structure.

> /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder.../&&: no such file or directory
>
> meaning the && wasn't parsed correctly.

`&&` was parsed correctly. It was parsed as a filename because that is how the underlying function that executes `COPY` command is implemented.

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
```

Also, note that one of the reasons for having just one (or just a small bunch) of `RUN` directives is that each of these is executed in its own intermediate container which is immediately removed once the particular `RUN` directive is executed which obviously produces an additional overhead that can be avoided by simply chaining the commands.

This is not the case with `COPY` though. Even if you have 100s `COPY` directives, all of these are executed without creating and removing any intermediate containers. Personally, I am not worried about having additional `COPY` directive if it makes the Dockerfile more readable. This doesn't affect build speed and/or size of the container in any significant way.