# Python script with numpy in dockerfile on Raspberry PI - libf77blas.so.3 error

Tags: python, docker, numpy, raspberry-pi

I want to run a Docker container on my Raspberry PI 2 with a Python script that uses numpy. For this I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY numpy_script.py /
RUN pip install numpy

CMD ["python", "numpy_script.py"]
```

But when I want to import numpy, I get the error message that libf77blas.so.3 was not found.
I have also tried to install numpy with a wheel from [www.piwheels.org](http://www.piwheels.org), but the same error occurs.

The Google search revealed that I need to install the liblapack3. How do I need to modify my Dockerfile for this?

---

**Inspired by the answer of om-ha, this worked for me:**

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY numpy_script.py /
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libatlas-base-dev \
    && pip install numpy

CMD ["python", "numpy_script.py"]
```

Comment: A. What's your host OS? B. From a host perspective, do you want this to be cross-platform (Windows/Linux)?

Comment: It's Raspberry Pi OS. Just want a lightweight docker container with a python script, not cross-platform

Comment: Done with my changes, check the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am in bed now, but will give it a try as soon as I wake up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working Dockerfile

```
# Python image (debian-based)
FROM python:3.7

# Create working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy project files
COPY numpy_script.py numpy_script.py

# RUN command to update packages & install dependencies for the project
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    && pip install numpy

# Commands to run within the container
CMD ["python", "numpy_script.py"]
```

### Explanation

1. You have an extra trailing `\` in your dockerfile, this is used for multi-line shell commands actually. You can see this used in-action [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments). I used this in my answer above. Beware the last shell command (in this case `pip`) does not need a trailing `\`, a mishap that was done in the code you showed.
2. You should probably use a working directory via `WORKDIR /app`
3. Run `apt-get update` just to be sure everything is up-to-date.
4. It's recommended to group multiple shell commands within ONE `RUN` directive using `&&`. See [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-which-is-better).

### Resources sorted by order of use in this dockerfile

1. [FROM](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#from)
2. [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir)
3. [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)
4. [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run)
5. [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd)

Comment: Hi, om-ha, thank you for given the working Dockerfile. I tried to build with above working Dockerfile in windows 10, which is working. However when I copied over image, and use docker to run the image on the Raspberry Pi 4, it says "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested." I tried add build parameter --platform linux/armv7, which takes hour to build on windows 10. Is this behavior expected?

Comment: @WangYufan When building, specify the platform like this `docker build --platform linux/arm/v7`

Comment: Also refer to [this issue](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/735#issuecomment-749709145) for some inspiration.

Comment: You can specify the platform in the dockerfile, refer to `[--platform=<platform>]` in [`FROM` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) e.g. `FROM --platform=linux/arm/v7 python:3.7`

Comment: Finally, this could prove useful too: [Multi-Platform Docker Builds](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/).

Comment: Thank you, I will walk through and try the above approaches.