# docker image - intermediate container issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have a dockerfile which downloads file through wget and in the next step when I try to "RUN unzip . I get the below error.

```
Step 10/27 : RUN wget http://artifactory.orbit8.com/artifactory/build-dependencies/7.2.0/ext-7.2.0.zip -P /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bb39b7a46fd1
Step 11/27 : RUN unzip /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip -d /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0
 ---> Running in 515e6e4e5456
unzip:  cannot find or open /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip, /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip.zip or /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip.ZIP.
```

Comment: You ran a wget on `ext-7.2.0.zip` and tried to unzip `epa-7.2.0.zip`

Comment: The other thing I'd check is if there's a `VOLUME /var/jenkins_home` declaration; that would cause the result of the `wget` to be lost (even if it had the right filename).  Can you edit the question to include the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

BMitch said it. you missed the right naming.
Also dont forget to execute wget and unzip and rm in one layer otherwise you will waste resources. ([Multiple RUN vs. single chained RUN in Dockerfile, which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223249/multiple-run-vs-single-chained-run-in-dockerfile-which-is-better))

Try this :

```
RUN wget http://artifactory.orbit8.com/artifactory/build-dependencies/7.2.0/ext-7.2.0.zip -P /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0 && \
    unzip /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip -d /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0 && \
    rm /var/jenkins_home/Extjs_7.2.0/epa-7.2.0.zip
```