# Understanding && and || in dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I am somewhat new to docker, and trying to understand why && and || mean in dockerfile RUN command. Is there a documentation that explains how they work?

Comment: Assuming you have unix based image, it means the same as in any shell script ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4510640/596285

Comment: What about Windows images?

Comment: It is not only about bash scripting but also efficiency of docker image. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39223249/12501050

Answer (score 3):

These are standard Bourne shell script operators. In short: the code after each `&&` will be evaluated only if part before these symbols is finished with exit code 0 (i.e., successfully). `||` is exactly the opposite, in that the code after it will be evaluated only if what was before the symbols finished with a non-zero exit code (i.e., failed).

Comment: How about Windows?

Comment: Don't have much experience with the Windows command line, but the operators behave the same according to multiple sources. E.g., https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting