# Why Docker container images become so large while deploying Python 3.6, Virtualenv, Flask, Gunicorn on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile, gunicorn

While deploying the flask application within virtualenv `python3 -m venv FLSK-ENV`

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM appcontainers/ubuntu:xenial

    MAINTAINER user <user>

    RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
            && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 -y \
            && apt-get update -y \
            && apt-get install -y python3.6-minimal python3.6-venv \
            && apt-get install -y git \
            && apt-get install python-pip -y \
            && pip install --upgrade pip \
            && pip install gunicorn \
            && mkdir -p /home/EZMOVE 

    WORKDIR /home/workdir

    RUN git clone -b develop --single-branch http://repo

    RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./prepareenv.sh"]

    RUN /bin/bash -c "source prepareenv.sh"

    EXPOSE 5000
```

So above Dockerfile will pull the minimal ubuntu-16.04 from "*appcontainers/ubuntu:xenial*" and will update and install only required packages like:

```
 1. python3.6
 2. git
 3. python-pip
 4. gunicorn
```

Then it will execute the '*prepareenv.sh*' to create the python3.6 virtual environment, activate venv and then install requirements.txt using pip, then it will expose the port and gunicorn will serv the Flask application..etc.

***But while creating the image the docker image size increase from 70MB to 550MB.***

while installing the packages it is installing the other packages like as follows:

```
    The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential bzip2 cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc
  gcc-5 gcc-5-base libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
  libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0
  libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  make manpages manpages-dev python python-all python-all-dev python-dev
  python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7
  python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc bzip2-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib
  g++-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libstdc++6-5-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake
  libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc locales
  libstdc++-5-doc make-doc man-browser python-doc python-tk
  python-setuptools-doc python2.7-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential bzip2 cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 gcc
  gcc-5 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0
  libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7
  libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libquadmath0
  libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev
  python python-all python-all-dev python-dev python-minimal python-pip
  python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7 python2.7-dev
  python2.7-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-5-base libc6 libstdc++6
3 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 76.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 210 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

So how to reduce the Docker image size ?

Comment: [See my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large/39078793#39078793)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following Dockerfile, it gets the size of the image down to 255 MB. "--no-install-recommends" ensures that only the required packages are installed and "rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" cleans up including any index files.

```
FROM appcontainers/ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update \
            && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common \
            && add-apt-repository -y ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 \
            && apt-get update \
            && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3.6-minimal python3.6-venv \
            && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git \
            && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python-pip \
            && pip install --upgrade pip \
            && pip install gunicorn \
            && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
            && mkdir -p /home/EZMOVE

WORKDIR /home/workdir

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Thanks #Dino,

I added the  extra argument in 'apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends', so some how it reduced the size of Ubunut 16.04 docker container from 550MB to 210MB.
so I am planning to host flask application using Gunicorn so, for this How can I optimised the Docker container, like 
1. will add only binary of flask app into the container, so for this I need not to install python-dev like packages.
2. While creating the docker container many layers  are geting created so how can I merge all previous layer into single layer.