# Saving docker container after updating the container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, save, docker-compose

I am an new bee to Docker and i am trying to create/use the existing image to bring up my application.  After reading couple of stackoverflow posts and Docker documentations I was able bring up my application using Docker containers. 
Now I am looking for correct way to saving the modified Docker container, So that I can reuse the container to bring up my application by running docker command.

I see people use $docker commit to save the docker container. If i run this command, where does the container gets saved ? will anybody else able to download my saved container ?

I am planning to deploy the saved docker container to the AWS cloud as well.

Any suggestions or comments on this would be helpful.

**Update to the post**
Here is my dockerfile which i use to download and build the container

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
COPY /app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN unzip /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
EXPOSE 8080
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
COPY config1.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/
COPY config2.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/properties/
COPY config4.properties /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app/conf/

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"
# Copy Entrypoint script in the container
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh / 
RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`If i run this command, where does the container gets saved ?`

On your local machine. Just type `docker images` and you will see it.

`will anybody else able to download my saved container ?`

No, because it's only on your local machine.

---

**But this is NOT the way how you should use docker!**
Don't modify the running container! Instead, write a `Dockerfile` and build your image via this Dockerfile.

Comment: ok. How do i ship this image to a different desktop machine ? for example i have updated a container which actually downloads a image from the official tomcat repository and i saved the container in my local machine using the $docker commit command. After that I want to ship this container to a different box or a desktop machine which is in the same network ? How can i do that ?

Comment: Best way is to use a Docker repository like Docker Hub: Do `docker push` on your local machine and `docker pull` on the remote. An (ugly) alternative is to export your image into a .tar file (`docker export`), copy this tar to your remote machine and import this tar (`docker import`).

Comment: I know that Docker Hub is where you download all the existing containers. If i do the $docker push, it will be available in the Docker Hub. Does that mean that anyone can access my container ? . But i like the other way of exporting my  image to a tar file and i can use the same in a different box as well. Between can i know why it is ugly ?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the dockerfile which i use to build the container

Comment: You can create private repos on Docker Hub which are only accessible for authorized users. // See this post for some hints on creating smaller Docker images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large/39078793

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#parent-command)

> Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a
>   documented and maintainable way.
>
> ...
>
> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes
>   mounted inside the container.

Commit a container:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS              NAMES
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            desperate_dubinsky
197387f1b436        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours                            focused_hamilton

$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3

f5283438590d

$ docker images

REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID                  CREATED             SIZE
svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d        16 seconds ago      335.7 MB
```

As you can see in the example the image saved is stored in the machine which runs the `docker commit`