# Docker build image size too big for postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to build a PostgreSql 9.6 docker image that has plv8 extension installed. Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM postgres:9.6

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y
RUN pip install psycopg2

RUN wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v2.3.0.tar.gz && tar -xvzf v2.3.0.tar.gz && cd plv8-2.3.0 && make

RUN cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8--2.3.0.sql /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/
RUN cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.control /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/
RUN cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/

RUN rm v2* && rm -rf plv8-2.3.0
RUN apt-get remove --purge wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y
RUN apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y
```

The resulting image size is 3.45 GB while the original image size from Docker hub is 235 MB. Any idea why the resulting image size is so big? How can I reduce its size ? I tried to reduce its size using [this link](https://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/) but unfortunately `docker import/export` loses the metadata.

**Update:**

I tried to consolidate all RUN statements into one.

```
FROM postgres:9.6

RUN apt-get update ; apt-get install wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y ; pip install psycopg2 ; wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v2.3.0.tar.gz ; tar -xvzf v2.3.0.tar.gz ; cd plv8-2.3.0 ; make ; cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8--2.3.0.sql /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/ ; cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.control /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/ ; cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/ ; rm v2* ; rm -rf plv8-2.3.0 ; apt-get remove --purge wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y ; apt-get autoremove -y ; apt-get autoclean -y
```

And the new size is 3.11 GB. Isn't it still big?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Docker container images so large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run commands using && as possible as you can.
Example:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential 
    postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y && \
    apt-get install wget make git python python-pip python-dev build-essential 
    postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libglib2.0-dev libc++abi-dev libc++-dev -y && \
    pip install psycopg2

RUN wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v2.3.0.tar.gz && tar -xvzf v2.3.0.tar.gz && cd plv8-2.3.0 && make

RUN cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8--2.3.0.sql /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/ && \
    cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.control /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/ && \
    cp /plv8-2.3.0/plv8.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/
.
.
.
```

And so on...
Because each RUN line will generate an image called dangling image with it's own size.

Comment: Use && instead of ;

Comment: For a best practice try to use "&& \" and put a command by line to make your Dockerfile more readable.

Comment: Tried ; and & same size :(

Comment: So this is the final size of your image as I see you customized the base image stgres:9.6 by injecting so many packages, I think that it's the minimal size you can touch!