# pytorch package too huge

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

After installing pytorch via

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir torch==1.9.1
```

I realised that corresponding docker layer is 1.78GB
Is there any way to reduce pytorch size? Current version is with GPU & Cuda 10.2

Comment: Not sure if this is the case but the big size you see may not be caused by torch itself but rather by how docker works. See "Why are Docker container images so large?" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394243/why-are-docker-container-images-so-large)

Comment: Pytorch is still 887 MB - quite large.